# Test promise inside dynamic import in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, promise

I have this kind of code:

component.ts

```
async ngOnInit() {
   import('dom-to-image').then(module => {
      const domToImage = module.default;
      const node = document.getElementById('some-id');
      domToImage.toPng(node).then(dataUrl => {
          // The test is not getting over here
      }).catch(() => {});
   });
}
```

component.spec.ts

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           ....
      }).compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    })
  )

  it('should create', async () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
}
```

So the question is, How do I mock this promise domToImage.toPng? Is there a solution so the test can continue its execution and resolve the promise?

[image: capture of the coverage]

Thanks in advance
Isma

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock module.default:

```
module.default = {
    toPng: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve('myExpectedResponseData')})
};
```

And a mock calling reject in error tests.
Note: If you cant mock module.default directly, try spyOnProperty

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had a similar problem and I couldn't spy on the `import` to mock it.

What I did to make the test happy was I moved it to its own method and I spied on that method.

```
async ngOnInit() {
   importDomToImage().then(module => {
      const domToImage = module.default;
      const node = document.getElementById('some-id');
      domToImage.toPng(node).then(dataUrl => {
          // The test is not getting over here
      }).catch(() => {});
   });
}

importDomToImage(): Promise<any> { // can make any more specific
  return import('dom-to-image');
}
```

The first `fixture.detectChanges()` is when `ngOnInit()` is called, so we have to mock before that.

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           ....
      }).compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      // mock here
      spyOn(component, 'importDomToImage').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({
        default: {
           toPng: (arg) => Promise.resolve('abc'), // dataUrl will be abc
        }
      }));
      fixture.detectChanges();
    })
  )

  it('should create', async () => {
    // await fixture.whenStable() to resolve all promises
    await fixture.whenStable();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
}
```

The above should hopefully do the trick and get you started.